# Magnetic flux direction in ac generator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Magnetic Flux Equation?
I am given this:

$$\Phi = BA \cos \text{angle}$$

But, I am confused to as what the angle means?

I know that magnetic flux is greatest when say for example, a coil's plane axis is perpendicular to the path of magnetic fields.

But that would be $90°$, and $\cos 90°$ would be $0$. That doesn't make sense.
I referred to this image but cannot understand how the angle is calculated.

[image: AC Generator]
image from [Macao Communications Museum (AC Generator)](http://macao.communications.museum/eng/exhibition/secondfloor/moreinfo/2_4_1_ACGenerator.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cos angle refers to the angle between area vector and magnetic field vector. Area vector points perpendicular to the area of coil. Magnetic field vector points from north pole of magnet to south pole.

Answer (score 0):

A diagram from your link

[image]

The magnetic flux certainly changes as $\cos({\rm angle})$ but the emf depends on the rate of change of magnetic flux with respect to time.  So the emf varies as $\sin({\rm angle})$

It terms of cutting lines of magnetic field the emf is greatest when the angle is $90^\circ$ i.e. the conductor is cutting lines at right angles and zero when the conductor is moving parallel to the lines at $0^\circ$.

Comment: I would have though that since the motor effect is strongest at 180 degrees, more work would have to be done against it then at any other angle, producing more voltage. I know this is wrong by the way, but could you elaborate pls?

Comment: @UbaidHassan  At $180^\circ$ there is no induces emf and so no current.