# Why is the induced current greatest when a generator's loop is in the direction of the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, inductance, electromagnetic-induction

This is a topic that has been confusing me for a while now. 
take this picture for instance

[image]

We know that a current is induced when a conducting loop experiences a change in magnetic flux. So I expected the current to be greatest when the normal vector of the loop is parallel to the magnetic fields, since that would be the orientation with the greatest amount of magnetic flux, which means that the current has to be greatest at that instance so that it can produce an opposing magnetic field strong enough to cancel the change in flux. But to my surprise, it turns out that current is greatest when the normal is perpendicular to the magnetic field (i.e. when there is no magnetic flux) and I can't for the life of me understand how does that make physical sense.

Can someone please help explain this point?
Thanks

Edit:
I am perfectly aware of the mathematical explanation of this phenomenon (i.e. derivative of cosine is sine). What I would like is a physical explanation.

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/292269/104696

Comment: The induced emf is greatest where the magnetic flux through the loop is changing at the fastest rate.  By inspection, this is obviously occurring at the point where the  sides of the wire loop are cutting through the magnetic field lines at the fastest rate.  This occurs when the sides of the wire loop are aligned with the magnetic field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced current is proportional to the time change in magnetic flux $$I∝d\Phi/dt=A\frac{d\vec B \vec n}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}AB\cos{\omega t}=-AB\omega sin \omega t$$ where $\vec B$ is the magnetic field, $\vec n$ is the normal vector of the loop surface, $A$ is the area of the loop, and $\phi=\omega t$ is the angle between the loop normal and the magnetic field $\vec B$. Thus the current is maximum when $\phi=\omega t=\pi/2+n\pi$  because then the *time change of the magnetic flux* $\Phi$ is maximal.

Comment: please check edit

Comment: At $\phi=\pi/2+n\pi$ the magnetic flux change through the loop simply  is fastest for constant $\omega$. This is a directly evident, purely geometrical fact.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated,the induced EMF,hence current,is varied due to change in the Magnetic Flux.So,the expression for change in magnetic flux(say F=BAcos(wt)),in time(say t),would be:-

dF/dt=BAwsin(wt)=BAwsin0
let BAw=E'
therfore: induced EMF(e)=E'sin0
So now,EMF will be max when 0=90deg.(As Sin 90deg.=1).
Its pretty easy to deduce!

Comment: please check edit